# Most suitable HTTP status to use for an expired login (form based login)

Tags: http, authentication

I am writing some code to respond in a useful way to an expired login in a web app. It's form-based login. It's the HTTP status code I'd like to decide upon.

I tried 401, but this causes an authentication dialog to pop up in the browser. I spotted some threads mentioning error "440 Login Expired" used in some Microsoft apps, but I can't find anything about that in the W3C docs, nor any other code which seems suitable for an expired form login.

So would it be ok to respond with 440 - is this a kind of ad-hoc standard? Or is there a better code that others use? Or is it a case of just make one up for the app?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This might be a close relative question to [Correct HTTP status code for login form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6110672/correct-http-status-code-for-login-form). Whether your login has expired or whether you have never had one should make no difference.

The answers given on that other question where:

1. 400 - accepted answer and I strongly disagree with it.
2. 401 - with a WWW-Authenticate header which may contain anything, it doesn't matter, browsers should (!?) ignore it if you do not put a basic or digest authentication challenge here.

But what I am missing is the real distinction as to how the login form is being delivered. It can be either 
 * injected as a response to the current request (that is what the 401 answer was suggesting to do)
 * or delivered with a redirect, e.g. 302 to a login page, which, once completed dialogue, will redirect back to the original request.

I have for 10 years run my application with 302 redirect to login page. But I do not like it any more. I want to return 401 so that my scripted agents, REST, etc. will do their stuff properly.

So, what needs to be done to really *settle* this question is to check how browsers behave when getting a 401 response with WWW-Authentication header that does not have a digest or basic challenge. If they always bring up their dialogue then it's a no-go no matter what we think would be the right and proper way of doing things.

I also need to send 401 with a Location: header and see if the browsers would redirect.